# Boot manager does not present me with OS choice

Tags: linux, windows-8, grub, linux-mint, uefi

I have installed Linux Mint 15 alongside Windows 8.When installing Mint the option I chose said install Mint alongside Windows 7 which I chose.

Once the system rebooted after the install,I was presented with the usual GRUB which presents me with a choice of Operating System.

My BIOS has an option called boot with the parameters set to Legacy Support and UEFI first.

My laptop is a Lenovo G505S,it uses MBR.How do I get the system to allow me to make a choice between OS.

I have tried enabling legacy boot first in my BIOS to no effect.

EDIT:I used a live cd of Linux Mint to run `bootinfoscript` as suggested by Rod Smith.
The [RESULTS](http://pastebin.com/UrXdueqm) say Im running Windows 7 which I know is not the case.Also,there is no mention of my installed Linux OS.

Comment: Do you have a hotkey to enter boot menu on the first screen? Usually it's `Esc` or `F1`..`F12`

Comment: No hotkey F2 for BIOS,F12 is boot order.

Comment: Boot order should be in BIOS (or rather UEFI, which is, technically speaking, not BIOS). F12 is probably the boot menu that lets you select boot method without altering permanent boot settings. Can you see OSes in that menu?

Comment: No,I can see where to boot from DVD/SATA HDD

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates to [a pastebin site.](http://pastebin.com/) Post the resulting URL here. Without this information, there are too many guesses required to answer your question reliably.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent within Windows

Comment: added results of running bootinfoscript

Answer (score 0):

The Bios has nothing to do with GRUB not displaying a boot menu.

If the only problem is that GRUB does not show the menu, you get around it by changing, in the file /etc/default/grub, these lines:

```
 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

in this way:

```
 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
```

Now do

```
 sudo update-grub
```

and when you reboot, keep the `Shift` key down, this will show the boot menu.

If however you have a corrupt MBR, you can fix it by using the `live distro` which you used to install Mint. When you have booted into it, download a utility called Boot-Repair: you find all relevant instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: BIOS doesn't, but UEFI possibly does. GPT drives don't have MBR and UEFI chooses which partition/OS to boot. Maybe it defaults to a loader, not bootsector, thus skipping GRUB completely.